# I need to link a typescript class to a angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the element class

```
export class Element {
    fields = []
}
```

And here is 2 field class

```
export class SmallText {
    value
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value
    }
}

export class LargeText {
    value
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

Lets say we have this element

```
export class Element {
    fields = []
    constructor(){
        this.fields.push(new SmallText("foo"))
        this.fields.push(new LargeText("bar"))
    }
}
```

Each field have a unique template for example

```
<!-- the small text is an input -->
<input>
<!-- but the large text is a textera -->
<textera></textera>
```

Now i want to loop the fields array and for each field show the respective template.

The solution i use now goes like this.

```
<field *ngFor="let field of element.fields" [inputField]="field"></field>
```

And inside the field component there is something like this:

```
<input *ngIf="inputField.constructor.name == 'SmallText'">
<textarea *ngIf="fieinputFieldd.constructor.name == 'LargeText'"></textarea>
```

This is troublesome because when i build in production all the class names are overwritten so i have to keep an index of all the class names in a service.

I would like to have a SmallText component and a LargeText component so when i loop inside the element.fields array each component is instantiated. This way i don't need to do a stupid logic to show the right template for the right field.

Is there a better solution than this?

Answer (score 0):

Use static so that after compilation it remains the same

```
export class SmallText {
    static type = 'SmallText';
    value
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value
    }
}

export class LargeText {
    static type = 'LargeText';
    value
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

template:

```
<input *ngIf="inputField.type == 'SmallText'">
<textarea *ngIf="fieinputFieldd.type == 'LargeText'"></textarea>
```

but I think it's better to do with components

**AppModule:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, SmallTextComponent, LargeTextComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  entryComponents: [SmallTextComponent, LargeTextComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**SmallTextComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-small-text',
  template: '<input/>',
})
export class SmallTextComponent { }
```

**LargeTextComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-large-text',
  template: '<textarea></textarea>',
})
export class LargeTextComponent { }
```

**AppComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<ng-container #container></ng-container>'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;
  private _components: Type<any>[];

  constructor(
    private _cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _injector: Injector,
  ) {
    this._components = [LargeTextComponent, SmallTextComponent, LargeTextComponent];
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._components.forEach(component => {
      const componentFactory = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(component);
      const componentRef = componentFactory.create(this._injector);
      this.container.insert(componentRef.hostView);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think too, its better to do it with components. How would you do it with components?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foreach-field-in-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

It's the same but with components.

You can choose and pass the type into your component field.

```
// field.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'field',
  template: `
    <input *ngIf="type == 'small-text'" name="{{name}}" [value]="value" />
    <textarea *ngIf="type == 'large-text'" name="{{name}}" [value]="value"></textarea>
  `
})
export class FieldComponent  {
  @Input() type;
  @Input() name;
  @Input() value;

}
```

And call it in your component template:

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <label>{{field.name}}: </label>
  <field [type]="field.type" value="{{field.value}}"></field><br><br>
</div>
```

The component array:

```
fields = [
    { type: 'small-text', name: 'foo', value: 'foo' },
    { type: 'large-text', name: 'bar', value: 'bar' },
    { type: 'small-text', name: 'moo', value: 'moo' },
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see your "fields" are real JavaScript class initialised with for example `new LargeText (...)`, so in this case, I think your best buddy is the [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator. This reference won't break after production build by the way.

Something goes like this:

**template**

```
<input *ngIf="isSmallText(inputField)">
<textarea *ngIf="isLargeText(inputField)"></textarea>
```

**component**

```
public isSmallText(field: SmallText | LargeText): boolean {
  return field instanceof SmallText;
}

public isLargeText(field: SmallText | LargeText): boolean {
  return field instanceof LargeText;
}
```

Also as @chris pointed out people may have concerns about using method calls in Angular template as it makes change detection trigger more than expected updates on this piece of template code. (case may be different depends on your component change detection strategy)

So below is a more production-ready code example (still using `instanceof`)

**template**

```
<input *ngIf="isSmallText$ | async">
<textarea *ngIf="isLargeText$ | async"></textarea>
```

**component**

```
// your field observable monitored when input changes
public inputField$ = ...;

public isSmallText$ = this.inputField$.map(field => field instanceof SmallText);

public isLargeText$ = this.inputField$.map(field => field instanceof LargeText);
```

And of course, when your business logic getting more complex (for example a dozen different type of fields), you'll want to do a bit of further refactor to deal with those type checking in an unified way, but that'll be out of scope for the original issue you want to resolve here.

But IMHO the performance sacrifice is something worth taking when you just started learning Angular. This will naturally go away when you get your hands dirty on reactive programming.

Comment: Call functions in Angular templates cause serious performance issues.

Comment: @Chris this example is only to show why `instanceof` is a better option in this scenario. But you are right I'll amend another example with production-quality code.

Comment: why do you think it is a better implementation than the one with static key?

Comment: Because it is an ECMAScript native feature that does exactly what needed to solve the issue in this thread. Also even if you use the static key in the template there is still performance issue, similar to a function call because Angular needs to check if `inputField.type == 'SmallText'` is true every time change detection runs. This is very different than using a plain variable.

Comment: yes but you have to write functions for each type, that's why I said it's better with ComponentFactoryResolver no need to check